# SQL Server Stored Procedure to return multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a stored procedure to return 10 rows of data to display an a page from the newest to the oldest data. I also need to get the next 10 rows and then the next 20 if the user hits a next or previous button. I know how to get one row at a time as I have below but am not sure how to return multiple rows.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetRow] 
    @RowIdent int,
    @Formula varchar(5) output,
    @Batch# int output,
    @Status int output,
    @AutoMode int output,
    @Time datetime output,
    @Mixer varchar(3) output,
    @QCTech varchar(3) output,
    @Notes varchar(max) output,
    @Deck int output,
    @Ident int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
       @Formula = [Formula],
       @Batch# = [Batch#],
       @Status= [Status],
       @AutoMode = [AutoMode],
       @Time = [Time],
       @Mixer = [Mixer],
       @QCTech = [QCTech],
       @Deck = [Notes],
       @Deck = [Deck],
       @Ident= [Ident]
  FROM [VenturaQC].[dbo].[QCLog] 
  WHERE
       [Ident] = @RowIdent

  Return 1
END
```

Sample QCLog table

```
Formula Batch#  Status  AutoMode    Time        Mixer   QCTech  Notes   Deck    Ident
F1235   1   2   1   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000 abc AT  Note 1  2   2
F1235   1   2   2   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000 abc AT  Note 2  2   3
F7175   1   1   1   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000 JH  EC  20#VIN. PER 5000#BATCH SIZE 5   6
F7175   1   2   1   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000 JH  KT  20#vin Resample 5   7
F7610   4   1   1   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000 JH  ec      6   8
F7610   4   5   1   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000 JH  KT      6   9
```

Thanks in advance
Kenny

Comment: If the data is to be consumed directly by a client and not other TSQL code, just run a plain `SELECT` on the table and it will generate a result set with all the rows you need, like a straight query. You can pass all the Ids in a table-valued parameter.

Answer (score 1):

"Just do it".

The stored procedure returns the result of a select statement. If your select statement selects multiple rows those - surprise surprise - will be returned. Basic sql for beginners - stored procedure or not, all select statements work the same.

> I also need to get the next 10 rows and then the next 20 if the user hits a next or previous 
>   button.

Impossible to do in a stored procedure as: the SP returns data, then is finished. It can not wait for a button click.

If you need to do paging, you need to do that in the UI and then call the SP with relevant parameters (i.e. skip and take parameters that you then put into the SQL).

Answer (score 1):

read this article. good one..
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs

Comment: That's for ASP.NET, but the OP never says anything about it, just about SQL Server.

Comment: yes, THe key is ROW_NUMBER(). from the sql code, i think he is using ms sql, so he can use Row_number(). good luck